# Child (5yrs) on Tier 4 visas has CAS. Family income questions

Tags: visa

Our daughter is enrolled in a school in England and our entire family (Father, mother, daughter (student) and son (2yrs) want to also follow. UK.Gov states anyone on a tier 4 visa cannot work but in order for us to make this work we would need the invome and thus work remotely.  Our entire family, according to UK.gov, can come to the UK as Parents of a child tier 4 visa holder and stay for the duration of her education.

We own and operate a small bookkeeping accountancy that we have successfully run remotely during extended travel - we work a total of 15 hours per week. We also have rental income of just over $5,000 per month.

I'm looking for an opinion on if we should all apply for a tier 4 but write a cover letter stating the sources of our income or would we be better off only applying for our daughter on a tier 4 and the rest of us apply for a long term tourist visa. Another possibility we've considered is a Sole Representative Visa as I do not currently work for our company and could be hire to set up a branch in England.

It's is our hope to let a home and live in England for two years total. It seems like somehow all of these pieces can fit together but the guidelines are vague and I don't want to apply incorrectly and get a negative mark on our immigration record.

Any advice or experiences shared would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You should not entertain the idea of running your business remotely from the UK while staying on a visit visa or the Parent of a Tier 4 child visa, since this would be working, a violation of the conditions of the visa.

The sole representative visa does not seem suitable to me, since it sounds to me (and will sound to the Home Office!) like the "branch in England" would be a scheme entirely constructed to allow you to get the visa. Even if this isn't the case, it is not permitted for the "sole representative" to be a "major shareholder" in the company, which presumably you are.

Ultimately, what you want is not possible. You can't just come to live in the UK. As the conditions of the Parent visa make clear, it is not intended that you make your primary home in the UK. Moving your whole family certainly looks to me like you would be making your primary home in the UK.

You need to rethink your plans. It's perfectly possible for you to take holidays in the UK. You should bear in mind that UKVI are suspicious of people without any UK travel history applying to stay 6 months. You should limit your initial holidays to a few weeks at most.

However, I'm not a professional. If you're paying the fees for an independent school for your daughter, I suspect you can afford to pay an immigration solicitor who may be able to come up with a more creative solution to what you want. This will be the best way of ensuring you don't get any negative marks on your immigration history.